# Changing style sheets depending on useragent

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, resolution, user-agent

```
<script language="Javascript">
var deviceIphone = "iPhone";
var deviceIpod = "iPod";

//Initialize our user agent string to lower case.
var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

//**************************
// Detects if the current device is an iPhone.
function DetectiPhone()
{
   if (uagent.search(deviceIphone) > -1)
   {document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"       href="ui/mobile/css/site.css">');
}
```

etc...

Above is the start of my code. I am trying to change the CSS file depending on what platform the user is using. I currently use media="screen ... " but it doesn't work with the amount of platforms I'm trying to use. I need something a lot more detailed/complex that is why I'm turning to useragents.

Any ideas why the css file doesn't change on my iPhone using the above code?

Better yet, any ideas on another way to change style sheets depending on the users platform/screen resolution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)){
    // code
}
```

match work with regular expression. Flag "i" indicate case insensitive ;)

Comment: Thanks, so I won't need the alltolowercase script then either? Will try now.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the code above doesn't work because you are converting the UA string to lowercase, but your target device strings are camelCased :)

The `search()` function is case sensitive by default

Comment: I did have it all lower case until someone pointed it out. Even when iphone is all lower case it still doesn't work. I will try the correct case and remove the alltolowercase.

Comment: Maybe you are falling victim to JavaScript's automatic semi-colon insertion mechanism? Unlike .net, in JavaScript it is recommended to put the opening curly brace on the same line as the function statement, not on the line below...Also, you should not use the language attribute of the script element. If you are using an old HTML doctype you can set the type attribute to text/javascript, but this is not required with HTML5.

Comment: Thank you, will try putting them on separate lines. Also we are a very multi-platform company and work with such old devices and also browsers so shouldn't I use it just to be on the safe side?

Comment: no no, they need to be on the same line, like this: function DetectiPhone() {

Comment: No, the language attribute should not be used. Use type="text/javascript" instead

Comment: Sorry I did mean same line, don't know why I wrote separate even after you said to put it on separate lines :)